# How to show abstract class containing other classes in Java UML class diagrams?

Tags: java, uml, abstract-class, abstract, class-diagram

Looking for clarification on how to draw the arrows for an abstract class which contains private variables of a different class type (i.e. non-primitive variables). I've got this as an example and was not sure if correct.

Image: [image: Example I made here]

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `Realization` which is meant more for interface realization you should use simple `Generalization` with a solid line instead. This is about inheritance where the concrete inherit from the abstract classes. This means also that the association is inherited which for a realization would not be the case.

Since [Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe) mentioned it: There is no need to repeat operations/attributes in the inheriting class. See pp. 100 of UML 2.5:

> Members that are inherited by a Classifier may be shown on a diagram of that Classifier by prepending a caret ’^’ symbol to the textual representation that would be shown if the member were not inherited. [...]
> Inherited members may also be shown in a lighter color to help distinguish them from non-inherited members. A conforming implementation does not need to provide this option.

Comment: Ah ok if I switch it to generalization would that arrow between the house and person abstract classes be correct?

Comment: Well, yes. Your class ConcreteHouse inherits the association and thus will have an association to ConcreteBuiding.

Comment: @ThunderBase moreover,  the abstract operations (if there are some) could be in italic, and the concrete classes should only mention the operations that it overrides, since it inherits the others.